# Jquery: How to show the number of contents we want

Tags: jquery

I have the HTML code

```
<div class="content">
    Question : <input type="text" size="30"/><br />
    Answer A :  <input type="text" size="30"/><br />   
    Answer B :  <input type="text" size="30"/><br />   
    Answer C :  <input type="text" size="30"/><br />   
    Answer D :  <input type="text" size="30"/><br />  
   Correct Answer :
        <input type="radio" name="a"/> A 
        <input type="radio" name="b"/> B 
        <input type="radio" name="c"/> C 
        <input type="radio" name="d"/> D 
</div>

Please select the number of questions you want to display
<select class="choice">
    <option selected="selected">Select</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<div class="display">

</div>
```

and here is jQuery code to handle

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content").hide();     

        $("select.choice").change(function(){
            var i = parseInt($(this).attr("value")) ;
            var j;
            for(j = 1; j<=i ; j++){
                $(".content").show().appendTo($(".display"));
            }  
        }); 
    })
```

But the result is only a question to be shown although I selected option "2" . So how can I display the number of questions when I select the option ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone

```
$(".content").clone().appendTo($(".display")).show();
```

Basically your code is moving the contents of .content to .display, so when you loop through there is nothing in .content after the first pass.  If you use clone() it will clone it or copy it and not move it.

You should also move .show() to the end after its been cloned. Otherwise you will be showing the original and not the clones in .display.

Comment: From http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/: "If an element selected this way is inserted elsewhere, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):"

Comment: Which is why you're using clone() first.  Because you are moving the clone not the original.  You want to actually move the clone.

Comment: `$(".content")` will cause a problem.  Loop 1: `$(".content").length = 1` Loop 2: `$(".content").length = 2`, you will end up with `$(".content").length = 3` when you pick `2` Either call `.first()` or create a template to clone from.

Comment: Good point.  Adding a class .template to the first .content and calling .removeClass('template') after its been cloned from each clone would do the trick.  So you would be cloning .template instead of .content